# <img onclick=""> (with inline function call) doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I have the following code:

```
<img 
   title="Delete file" 
   onclick="DeleteFormAttachment('05177434-3132-4cd8-8e31-bae26dde194e');" 
   src="../SiteAssets/images/file_delete.png">
```

When the user clicks the image, the `DeleteFormAttachment` function is supposed to run. The first line in that function is a call to `window.confirm()`, which makes it very obvious when the function runs or doesn't run. If it doesn't run, there's no popup dialog.

So this code works fine in Chrome, but fails in IE11. Nothing happens when the user clicks the `<img>`.

The weirdest thing is that I managed to make it work as follows: 
- Open Dev Tools in IE11.
- Copy the content of the `onclick` attribute, and leave it blank. Press Enter to save the change to DOM. 
- Edit the `onclick` attribute again and paste the exact same call to `DeleteFormAttachment`. Press Enter. 
- Now the function runs when the user clicks on the `<img>`.

That is a very strange behaviour. Any ideas?

Comment: May be there is an issue in function 'DeleteFormAttachment()`what the browser let break down. Because we don't know your source code, we only can guess.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but have you considered using a pure JavaScript event handler instead, rather than embedding the `onclick` event into your HTML?

Comment: try using `<noscript>this browser doesn't addmit scripts </noscript>`, if the browser show it its because doesnt addmit it

Comment: @reporter There are no JS errors, the code runs fine in Chrome, and the code runs fine when I use dev tools to remove and re-add the onclick handler.

Comment: Works well in Internet Explorer 11: https://jsfiddle.net/aaxvw1en/

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other events that are fired on click of the img?

Comment: Maybe a charset problem? It can be: you save a file on a correct charset but server through data on another charset, and that confuses to IE11 and it can't run. So when you remove and add the attribute again, you are writing on the IE11 charset. Are you sure all your charsets are setted fine? Server, html and file savings.

Comment: Though this is likely a problem with IE settings, as others have pointed out, you should consider wrapping the image in a ```<buttton>``` element, and assigning the click event to the button instead, so that keyboard users can interact with it as well.  (images aren't inherently focusable so keyboard users would never be able to interact with the image in the way you currently have your code setup)

Answer (score 0):

Found that the problem only occurs in IE11 inside an Azure Virtual Machine running Windows Server 2012.

If I run IE9 in another VM, or if I run IE11 on my own computer, the code works fine.

I assume the problem is in IE11 security settings on the server, although I don't know which settings exactly.

Comment: So you can write a better code than your current code, that's very bad practice.

Comment: I mean: handle the event trough javascript and not on the HTML

Answer (score -1):

Just Do allow script in your ES11 browser like,

[image]

And then you are able to do this task, see

[image]

Thank you